# How organize data from server on Android client

Tags: android

I develop Android client, that get orders list from server. For http requests I use Retrofit library, and wrap api service in class `ApiClient`

```
public class ApiClient {
    private ApiService apiService;

    public ApiClient() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'")
                .create();
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.API_SERVER)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .build();
        apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);

    }
    public ApiService getApiService() {
        return apiService;
    }
}
```

Now in `MainActivity` I call `gerOrders` of `ApiService` interface to get list of orders.

```
ApiService service = new ApiClient().getApiService();
service.getOrders(callback);

Callback callback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void success(Object o, Response response) {
        Log.d("TestObject", new Gson().toJson(o));
    }
    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
    }
};
```

But this orders list is may be used in other Activities, and I think, it's not good get data right inside Activity or Fragment. How I can organize this code well?

Comment: How frequently your app is intended to  fetch data from server?

Comment: Once a minute or, may be serveral seconds. But case, when data fetches once a hour or a day is also interesting for me.

Comment: Then you can just call getOrders() method in other activity to get orders data if you want data so frequently. What is your exact problem?

Comment: I'm newbie Java/Android developer, and want to know, is my way is correct? And does it good call getOrders() from Activity? May be I need ContentProvider or Service for this?

Comment: See you can not use `contentProvider` here because it is used to share data among apps in a device. You can use Service if response is going to take long time, i can't see this case here. So you need to invoke network call method is `AsyncTask` that will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked implementation of you code. No need of `AsyncTask` this implementation is already asynchronous. You are using correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delegate this task to some helper, like DataHelper (you will find better name :) ), by this way activities, fragments, controllers can access it easily